# overpass query: select area/polygon with certain node in it

Tags: overpass-api

I want to select all polygons with

> tourism=camp_site and tourism=caravan_site without the key
>   'sanitary_dump_station'

but where **a node is located inside the boundary** with the tag

> amenity=sanitary_dump_station

I tried different approaches and ended up with this:

```
 [out:json][bbox:{{bbox}}][timeout:120];

node ["amenity"="sanitary_dump_station"] ->.a;
.a is_in ->.b;
way(pivot.b)->.x;
way.x["tourism"~"caravan_site|camp_site"][!"sanitary_dump_station"]->.z;
(.z; .a; );
out geom;
>;
out skel qt;
```

In the results I find some campings without the key 'sanitary_dump_station', eg.: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/116540519#map=19/50.22837/1.61213, while there is a node within its boundaries (https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work with arbitrary polygons as of today, or to be more precise, there has to be a matching area created beforehand on the server, subject to specific area creation rules. Those rules usually require a name tag to be present on the respective polygon.

You can use the following query, which depends on the existence of areas. Effectively, this means that your camp or caravan site has to have a name=* tag - otherwise no corresponding area exists on the Overpass API instance and you will get incomplete results, similar to your experience with is_in in your question: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRE -

This issue is currently being tracked in https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/77 and at this time there's no official solution available yet to analyze camp/caravan sites without a name, where no corresponding area exists on the Overpass instance.

However, you can try the following prototype in the meantime, which creates areas on-the-fly and is not bound by the mentioned area creation rules on the server: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRB - (**for testing purposes only**)

Comment: As I understand well. The problem is due to the lack of a name?  And when I try both -  my query and your sollution - they gives the same result... Which one is then the 'better' one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second question, can you elaborate a bit what you're trying to achieve with that random name and why do you need it?

Comment: The root cause for this behavior is that way 116540519 doesn't have a corresponding area on the Overpass API instance, hence is_in doesn't return an area. Official Overpass instances don't support this kind of ad-hoc area creation yet. That's what GIthub issue #77 is all about.  Bottom line: your query doesn't work the way you intend it to work. In your example https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRl - the inputset .z is even empty, so results of that query are fairly random and don't match your requirements at all.

Comment: the inputset .z is empty because of the fixed boundingbox which should be returning the camping without the name.  But when you set it to {{bbox}}(https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GSG) it gives me the same results als yours

Comment: Again, results will be different, and depend on the existance of a name=* tag on the surrounding way. If you're happy to accept incomplete results (which don't include any campsites without a name), then there isn't much I can do about it and we can stop here. Can you easily spot that your query returns a different result by comparing your query https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GSZ (returning no result) with prototype https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GT0 (finds a result). Also your query doesn't find way 652040499 with Node 6113645896 inside.

Comment: As far as I can see:
my query: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GSG no result, 
your queries:
https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRE no result,
https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GTO gives result.

Comment: Did you actually read my answer? That's exactly what I have written: _otherwise no corresponding area exists on the Overpass API instance and you will get incomplete results, similar to your experience with is_in in your question: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRE -_

Comment: I did read your answer! And I'm glad that you want help me.  Perhaps there is a misunderstanding about the https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRE. I did not write that, because I'm not familiar with the foreach-clause.

Comment: Query overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRE starts by finding all campsite ways first, finds a corresponding area by using `map_to_area;`, then iterates over each single area and tries to find all amenities inside each area. Your query works the other way around: you find determine all amenity nodes, and try to find out if they are inside a campsite way. The reason why I modeled the query this way was the prototype query https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GRB, where I cannot use `is_in;`. I tried to make my two queries as similar as possible to each other so it's easier to see what's happening.

Comment: OK, now I understand your logic. But as I understand well from your answer: I cannot use that prototype.  Any idea when it will be released?

Comment: No, that's not clear yet, and a bit related to the nature of a prototype.